# Is it possible to calculate implied probability of >=X% return based on implied volatilities from options

Tags: equities, implied-volatility, probability

**My question is:** Is it possible to imply either the upside or downside (one sided) probability from looking at implied volatilities of stock options?

**Let's take an example:** say you had Stock A at $50, with a 3M ATM Option with an Imp. Vol of 20%.

Is there a way, using perhaps non-ATM options, or some combination of options perhaps(?), to calculate the implied probability of Stock A being >10% by expiry (let's say 3m)?

Comment: You can get the risk neutral implied probability by pricing an undiscounted digital call or put - the distribution is only valid on expiration date.  The pricing is based on the digital price with skew - for a digital put: $P=N(-d_2)+\frac{d \sigma}{dK}\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}$ where $C$ is the price of a vanilla call - i.e. black scholes digital put + skew*vega.

Comment: Right. More generally, the full risk-neutral distribution can be inferred using the so-called Breeden-Litzenberger identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a variety of methods in this paper: Mizrach, Bruce, [Estimating Implied Probabilities From Option Prices and the Underlying](http://econweb.rutgers.edu/mizrach/pubs/[42]-2010_Handbook.pdf), in Cheng-few Lee and Alice C. Lee (eds.), Handbook of Quantitative Finance and Risk Management, New York: Springer-Verlag, 2010, 515-29.

MathWorks has an example of a method coded in Matlab: [Estimating Option-Implied Probability Distributions for Asset Pricing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/estimating-option-implied-probability-distributions-for-asset-pricing.html).

You may also be interested in this simpler article: [Option Prices Imply A Probability Distribution](https://www.globalcapital.com/article/k6543wh6f19l/option-prices-imply-a-probability-distribution)

To find other methods, you may need to search for papers on Google Scholar.